# Get latest two files using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to extract two ami id's from below output that are latest by date and time. How do I do that with python ? expected result: ami-x1, ami-x9

```
for image in images:
    created_date = datetime.strptime(image.creation_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
    print(image.id, created_date)
```

output:

```
ami-x1 2018-03-14 14:53:38
ami-x2 2018-03-13 14:34:34
ami-x3 2018-03-09 16:24:49
ami-x4 2018-03-12 14:32:44
ami-x5 2018-03-13 15:29:37
ami-x6 2018-03-07 15:38:03
ami-x7 2018-03-08 15:33:44
ami-x8 2018-03-06 23:20:24
ami-x9 2018-03-13 17:01:15
ami-x10 2018-03-05 15:43:09
```

I can also generate image.id filename which has epoch timestamp. Is it easier to extract latest two using filename epoch ?

```
test1-useast2-1521039086
test2-useast2-1520951547
test3-useast2-1520612589
test4-useast2-1520865070
test5-useast2-1520954877
test6-useast2-1520436979
test7-useast2-1520523129
test8-useast2-1520378310
test9-useast2-1520960373
test10-useast2-1520264490
```

please let me know if you have any inputs.

Comment: "Is it easier to extract latest two using filename epoch ?" - it's definitely going to use less CPU cycles, i.e. it is going to be "easier" for the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use the builtin function `sorted()` with the power of `lambda`s:

```
first, second = sorted(
    images,
    key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.creation_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z"),
    reverse=True
)[:2]
print(first.id, second.id) # get and print id values
```

Comment: I didn't think it would be this easy. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: Perfect, it would also be a good idea to check whether if the sorted list has at least two elements, otherwise the `=` could cause problems at runtime.